# exceljs how to set header in different row

Tags: node.js, exceljs

Hi i'm working with the exceljs library for node, and I'm reading a file, used as template for our excels, I want to use the addrows function with the headers properties of the columns, but I dont see in the documentation how to put the header on another row different from the first.

I am doing this.

```
var headers = [
  {header:'Cliente',key:'client_name'  ,width: 18}, //i need something like startRow:2
  {header:'N° Visitas',key:'visits'  ,width: 10},
  {header:'Visitas Periodo Anterior',key:'visits_old'  ,width: 10},
  {header:'Ultima visita',key:'last_visit',style: { numFmt: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss' },width: 22},
  {header:'Ultima Persona en Visitarlo',key:'device_name'  ,width: 18}
];

var libro  = workbook.xlsx.readFile(template_file)
  .then(function() {
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);

    worksheet.columns = headers;
    worksheet.addRows(data);

    //row.height=40;
    worksheet.getRow(1).hidden=false;
    worksheet.getRow(2).hidden=false;

    //row.height=40;
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile(output)
```

Note: sorry if i misspell something.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dobCol = worksheet.getRow(1); // You can define a row like 2 , 3

dobCol.header = [{
{header:'Cliente',key:'client_name'  ,width: 18}, //i need something like startRow:2
  {header:'N° Visitas',key:'visits'  ,width: 10},
  {header:'Visitas Periodo Anterior',key:'visits_old'  ,width: 10},
  {header:'Ultima visita',key:'last_visit',style: { numFmt: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss' },width: 22},
  {header:'Ultima Persona en Visitarlo',key:'device_name'  ,width: 18}
}];
```

Comment: I tried it, and in my case the appended rows started from: var dobCol = worksheet.getRow(4), tho the header of the table were still on the first row, tho what I needed was to set the start row form header columns to be 4th row:(